# Replace text from form with data from csv in PHP

Tags: php, csv, replace

I may be doing it wrong but I don't see what's going wrong.

Specifically: someone can fill out an online form with a message and upload a CSV. In this message, the user can indicate which text should be changed by a value in the CSV.

```
%%1%% = column 1 from CSV
%%2%% = column 2 from CSV
....
```

The problem is that every message that is sent always contains the contents of the first row of the CSV, and the values are also not converted correctly.

[image: content csv]

**An example is:**

*Input user:*

```
Hi %%3%% %%2%%

Key: %%4%%
Inhouse: %%5%%
Pictures: %%6%%
Certificate: %%7%%
```

*Output in the sent message:*

```
Hi 6584 Peter

Key: Yes
In-house: Permission
Pictures: A
Certificate:
```

*While it should be like this:*

```
Hi Peter Pauls

Key: 6584
Inhouse: Yes
Pictures: Permission
Certificate: Yes
```

**This is my code:**

```
<?php
session_start();

require_once("../../includes/config.php");
include("../../includes/smartschool.php");

$titel   = htmlspecialchars($_POST['titel']);
$bericht = urldecode($_POST['bericht']);
$numcols = htmlspecialchars($_POST['cols']);
$csv     = strtolower($_POST['csv']);

$i = 0;   

$smartschool = new SmartschoolConnection;

if (($handle = fopen('uploads/'.$csv.'', 'r')) !== FALSE) { // Nagaan of CSV correct uitgelezen kan worden

    while (($data = fgetcsv($handle, 1000, ";")) !== FALSE) { // Inhoud van CSV doorlopen   

        // Inhoud bericht aanpassen op basis van inhoud CSV
        while ($i <= $numcols) {

            $bericht = str_replace('%%'.$i.'%%', $data[$i], $bericht);
            
            ++$i;
        }

        $sRecipient     = $data[0];
        $sTitle         = $titel;
        $sBody          = $bericht;
        $sSender        = $_SESSION['username'];
        $aAttachments   = null;
        $iType          = 0;

        $smartschool->sendMsg($sRecipient, $sTitle, $sBody, $sSender, $aAttachments, $iType);

        echo "Smartschool bericht verzonden naar <strong>".$sRecipient."</strong><br />";

    }
}

sleep(5);

?>
```

Can someone help me with this or push me in the right direction?

I've already done some searching but I'm not getting any results, I'm not sure what exactly to look for in English since everything is always translated from Dutch.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first index of `$data` is 0, but in your mask is 1: you have to reduce all the placeholders by one:

```
Hi %%2%% %%1%%

Key: %%3%%
Inhouse: %%4%%
Pictures: %%5%%
Certificate: %%6%%
```

Also your `while` is wrong. You run two useless loops: the one of the initial 0 and the final one. Change it in this way:

```php
$i = 0;
while (++$i < $numcols) {
    $bericht = str_replace('%%'.$i.'%%', $data[$i], $bericht);
}
```

Comment: Hi fusion3k, thanks for your response. That is clear to me now and working like 
expected.

The other problem still remains, the contents of $bericht are always the values of the first row of the CSV, what am I missing here?

Comment: After first sub-while all placeholders are already replaced, so `str_replace` matches nothing. You have to reset`$bericht` content before each sub-loop: `$i = 0; $bericht = 'Hi %%2%% ... '; while ...`